# Add text in woocommerce_thankyou if order status is complete

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

I need to add a custom text that is displayed on the thank you page, if the order has been processed and has a completed status.

I am using the following code in the "woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table" hook and it works perfectly, but when I use it in the "woocommerce_thankyou" hook it generates errors.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'complete_custom_text' );

function complete_custom_text( $order ) {
    $status = $order->get_status();
    if(($status === 'completed')){
    echo '<p><b>Text (Custom) 5:</b> Perfect.</p>';
    }
}
```

If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving order_id in that hook, use `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` to get the order before reading the status.

Comment: I understand you, I already have the code working perfectly. Thanks a lot.